# how to fix error in python code (elif statement )

Tags: python

This is my code below, it is saying that there is an error but i cannot understand the error (the '^' is pointing at the ':' of the elif statement):
File "", line 47
elif:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

''    print ("there are 27 sticks")

```
sticks = 27 

player1 = True 
Ai = False 

print ("there are 27 sticks, pick the last one !")

print("1")
print("2")
print("3")

while player1 == True:
    
    inp = int(input("Enter the number of sticks you want to take: "))

    if inp == 1:
        inp = "1: 1 stick taken"
        sticks = sticks -1
        print (sticks)
        player1 = False 
        Ai = True 
    elif inp == 2:
        inp = "2 sticks taken"
        sticks = sticks - 2
        print (sticks)
        player1 = False 
        Ai = True 
    elif inp == 3:
        inp = "3 sticks taken"
        sticks = sticks - 3
        print (sticks)
        player1 = False 
        Ai = True 
    else:
        print("Invalid input!")
        
        
while Ai == True:
    if sticks == 7:
        InpAi = 3
        sticks = sticks - InpAi
        print (sticks)
        player1 = True 
        Ai = False 
    elif: 
        print ("")
    
    else: 
        ''
```

Comment: Aside from being invalid syntax (as Python has helpfully pointed out), `elif` without a condition expression after it doesn't really make much logical sense; at that point, why not just elect to use `else`...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
while Ai == True:
    if sticks == 7:
        InpAi = 3
        sticks = sticks - InpAi
        print (sticks)
        player1 = True 
        Ai = False 
    elif: # <= add condition here if any otherwise remove that line :)
        print ("")
    
    else: 
        ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` tree in the second `while` loop has the structure `if... elif... else` but the `elif` doesn't have a condtion. It's throwing an error because there is no condtion.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared an elif without a variable to check against, you need to put something like

```
elif something == 'something else':
    do this
```